# Play + Scala -> Validate IP Json data

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

I am trying to validate JSON payload in POST request in Play Controller. I am very new to Play & Scala world.

Below code is what I have got so far. This works fine without any input validation. Now I am trying to add validation to IP address fields on IPRangeStr class and running into issues. I am not able to figure out the validation to json list that contains enum.

Thanks

```
object listTypes extends Enumeration {
  type listTypes = Value
  val TypeA= Value("TypeA")
  val TypeB = Value("TypeB")
  val Unknown = Value("Unknown")

  def withNameWithDefault(name: String): Value =
    values.find(_.toString.toLowerCase == name.toLowerCase()).getOrElse(Unknown)
}

case class IPRangeStr(firstIP: String, lastIP: String, listType: listTypes, action: String)


@Singleton
class DataController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSvc: IPDataActorService)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  implicit val listTypeEnumFormat = new Format[listTypes.listTypes] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(listTypes.withNameWithDefault(json.as[String]))
    def writes(listEnum: listTypes.listTypes) = JsString(listEnum.toString)
  }

  implicit val ipRangeStrReads: Reads[IPRangeStr] = Json.format[IPRangeStr]
  implicit val ipRangeStrWrites = Json.writes[IPRangeStr]

  def process = Action.async(parse.json[List[IPRangeStr]]) { implicit request =>
   if(validationSuccess){    
        // process if validation successfull 
        Ok 
      } else {
        BadRequest // validation error
      }
    } recoverWith {
      case e: Exception  =>
        Future(InternalServerError)
    }
  }
}
```

**#Edit-1**
My final solution based on @cchantep ans

```
val validIPPattern: String = "(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])"

def isValidIP(ip:String) = ip.matches(validIPPattern)

implicit val ipRangeStrReads: Reads[IPRangeStr] =
    Json.format[IPRangeStr].filter { ipR =>
      isValidIP(ipR.firstIP) && isValidIP(ipR.lastIP)  //true  or false, according validation of ipR
}     

implicit val ipRangeStrWrites = Json.writes[IPRangeStr]
```

> When using Json.format, is not required to have a second call to
>   Json.write for the same type, as OFormat is able to read and write.

If I remove my write, I get an exception in my controller when I convert object to Json string.

Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

> I would rather use enumNameReads and enumNameWrites.

This is good to know shorthand. I ended up using my previous solution that converts json string to lowercase before converting to enum.

> It's recommended to name type with an initial cap, without final "s"
>   for plural (e.g. ListType).

I agree completely on this. Unfortunately it's part of legacy code which I don't want to refactor right now.

Comment: Rather use `Json.reads` for `ipRangeStrReads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a monadic type, the function `.filter` is available for `Reads`.

```scala
implicit val ipRangeStrReads: Reads[IPRangeStr] =
  Json.format[IPRangeStr].filter { ipR =>
    true // or false, according validation of ipR
  }
```

> When using `Json.format`, is not required to have a second call to `Json.write` for the same type, as `OFormat` is able to read and write.

I would rather use `enumNameReads` and `enumNameWrites`.

```scala
implicit val r = Reads.enumNameReads(listTypes)
implicit val w = Writes.enumNameWrites[listTypes.type]
```

> It's recommended to name type with an initial cap, without final "s" for plural (e.g. `ListType`).